# Update value printed to console

Tags: java, scala, read-eval-print-loop

I'm attempting to update a value printed to the console in order to implement a simple REPL that supports predictive commands.

So after "->" is printed to the screen using

```
Console.print("->")
```

and the user enters "d" followed by the "tab" key then then the existing output "->" should be converted to "-> dir"

I read the input using :

```
val input = scala.io.StdIn.readLine()
```

I have yet to implement the listener to determine when the tab key is pressed. At this point I'm attempting to prove if command line output can be updated in place.

Comment: Consider a library such as [jline](https://jline.github.io/)

Comment: You can try "\r", e.g. `for (i <- 1 to 10) {
      Thread.sleep(1000)
      print(s"$i\r")
    }`